# Else statement within drag and drop function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, drag-and-drop

I want to do a conditional drag and drop, to allow only elements with the class "droppable" to be dropped. I added a condition to the drop function but the “else” statement doesn’t seem to work. The else statement should display a “try again” message when an attempt is made to drop an element without the class "droppable". The else statement seems to be ignored though, it always shows the "good job" message, and appends the element that should not be appended.

Here's the code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("id", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("class", ev.target.className);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var droppableElement = ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
    var elementClass = ev.dataTransfer.getData("class");
    if ((elementClass = "droppable")) {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(droppableElement));
        $("#goodjob")
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(500)
            .fadeOut(500);
    } else {
        $("#tryagain")
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(500)
            .fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

```css
#dropArea {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 10px 30px 30px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

#dropItems {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.message {
  display: none;
}
.droppable {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
}
.notdroppable {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="goodjob" class="message">good job!</p>
    <p id="tryagain" class="message">tryagain!</p>
    <div id="dropArea" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <p>drop here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="dropItems" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <p>items to drop</p>
      <p
        id="drag1"
        draggable="true"
        ondragstart="drag(event)"
        width="336"
        height="69"
        class="droppable"
      >
        droppable
      </p>

      <p
        id="drag1"
        draggable="true"
        ondragstart="drag(event)"
        width="336"
        height="69"
        class="notdroppable"
      >
        not droppable
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] with relevant frameworks, HTML, JS and CSS

Comment: @mplungjan thanks! I clarified the question and added a code snippet, so you can better see the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning in the condition statement rather than comparing. It is not `false`, so the code in the `else` statement never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You had an assignment = instead of comparison ===

`if(elementClass = "droppable")`

should be

`if(elementClass === "droppable")`

This works as expected

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("id", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("class", ev.target.className);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var droppableElement = ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
    console.log(droppableElement)
    var elementClass = ev.dataTransfer.getData("class");
    if ((elementClass === "droppable")) {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(droppableElement));
        $("#goodjob")
            .fadeIn(500).append(droppableElement+": "+$("#"+droppableElement).text())
            .delay(500)
            .fadeOut(500);
    } else {
        $("#tryagain")
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(500)
            .fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

```css
#dropArea {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 10px 30px 30px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

#dropItems {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.message {
  display: none;
}
.droppable {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
}
.notdroppable {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="goodjob" class="message">good job!</p>
    <p id="tryagain" class="message">tryagain!</p>
    <div id="dropArea" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <p>drop here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="dropItems" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <p>items to drop</p>
      <p
        id="drag1"
        draggable="true"
        ondragstart="drag(event)"
        width="336"
        height="69"
        class="droppable"
      >
        droppable
      </p>

      <p
        id="drag1"
        draggable="true"
        ondragstart="drag(event)"
        width="336"
        height="69"
        class="notdroppable"
      >
        not droppable
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```